# SQL Server: Does the sysadmin role encompass all the other roles?

Tags: sql-server, security

When creating a new login on SQL Server you have to explicitly add server roles to that user. You have the option of checking the 'sysadmin' role along with all the other roles. Is there any point to this?

I.e. if you add the 'sysadmin' role to a user surely that encompasses all the other roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to add any server roles to a new user, those are optional (although it is best to leave the public role checked).

The sysadmin role encompasses all other roles, and is deity level access within SQL Server, granting you the rights and permissions to do whatever you want with the instance.